# Why position sticky is not working with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, sticky

I am trying to make sticky div inside div `col-md-3` , it working fine if I don't use `col-md-3` class, please tell what I am doing wrong,

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-3">
    <div class="sticky" style="border:1px solid; color:red">sticky</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9" style="height:1000px; border:1px solid; background:red">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: typo: `positon` --> `position`

Answer (score 0):

The sticky position is happening due to parent div (.col-3) because it have display flex property with this it's getting height equal to the div (col-9).

In short:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div class="2" style="height="500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Now in above HTML the div class 1 also get the height = div class 2 (500px).

Any element(position:sticky) inside div class 1 is sticky for next 500px.

> If any element is sticky then it also has same defined parent height.